# Evolution and Gnome Calendar keep asking me for my online account password

Tags: gnome, evolution, calendar, online-accounts

I have connected to my Gmail account with Evolution once just to download my email.  I didn't save my Gmail account password in Gnome Keyring and do not plan to for the moment.  Since then Gnome Calendar, and sometimes Evolution, keep asking me every half an hour or so for my Gmail account password.  How can I explain to them that I am not going to give them my Gmail accout password (at least for now)?

I know that I can somehow erase all traces of my Gmail account from Evolution, but this is not a solution for me because I want to keep the downloaded Gmail messages and to be able to download new ones from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Evolution is set to automatically collect email every 30 minutes. Go to the Evolution preferences and change the setting to either: `manual`, or `never` check, or remove the `checkmark` that enables this function. I don't have Evolution installed here, so I can't give you the exact location where you can find that setting.

Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks.  Indeed, i have found how to disable checking for new email for gmail account in Evolution.  I couldn't find any relevant preferences in Gnome Calendar, but it turned out that there are some calendar settings in Evolution.  It is impossible to disable synchronizing an online calendar completely, but it is possible to set the synchronization delay to, say, 10^6 days, which should be not very annoying.  Anyway, both Google calendar and Evolution keep asking me for a password on startup.